# Parse CSV and display to textview

Tags: java, android, csv, textview

I've got a CVS file. and i want my android application to read it and display it in a textview.
could you give me a example how to do this?

Comment: start from here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

Comment: Do you need to parse that CSV ?

Comment: it would be nice. but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.csv");
String s = "";
while(scanner.hasNextLine());
    s+=scanner.nextLine();
String[] values = s.split(",");
```

this is a 2n process, if you want to monkey around with substring you could probably get it down to n

here is to add it to the textview

```
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    t.setText(values[i]);
    layout.addView(t);
}
```

You can add the layout in th xml, or in the code itself by using setContentView(layout);

You can use layout params too by doing

```
 YourLayoutType.layoutParams params = new YourLayoutType.layoutParams(LayoutParams.whatLayoutTypeYouWant, LayoutParams.whatLayoutTypeYouWant); //(it goes width, height).
```

and then use them for your layout with

```
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Note: All this code should be in the Activity code file.

Comment: it depends on how you want it to display in a textview, every value on a separate line?

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I've made those methods because of Scanner was not working for me:

```
public ArrayList<String> readFileLines(File file)
{
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            lines.add(line);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot open file to read: " + e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot close file after saving: " + ex);
        }
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Usage:

```
    for (String line: readFileLines(new File("file.csv")))
    {
        String[] values = line.split(";");
        // values[0] would be first value of line, values[1] would be second etc.
    }
```